# Pycharm 2020.1.2 - .py file - Open File in Project

Tags: python, pycharm

I came back to pycharm for a project from SublimeText and updated to Pycharm 2020.1.2, I needed to quickly run a .py file, but when I double click the file, it opens the script in a view where I can edit but not run, so every time I have to go to File->Open File in Project. I don't remember having to do that in earlier versions of Pycharm, how can I circumvent that and always have Pycharm open a .py file in Project view?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Right click -> Run` works for you?

Comment: @Adirio i have added a couple of screenshot to demonstrate that I don't. Unless I choose Open File in Project... I don't get all the other functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started PyCharm in the light edit mode, check this blog post https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/lightedit-mode/

Comment: Thank you for this, the post never came up in my searches. I went through both the post and the comments and unfortunately, although people asked about how can this feature be disabled, there was no solution. Regardless, I am going to accept this as a solution since it's the only comment that provided information on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also have pycharm and usually I do Right click on the file -> open with -> pycharm

Comment: I added a couple of pictures to illustrate what I see on my end. Neither double click nor right click open with pycharm doesn't make a difference. As I said in the description, I only noticed this behavior after I updated to 2020.1.2

Comment: one the left of the screen there's your project directory, if you open it you can right-click on it and choose run 'Name_of_the_file'  without even open it

Answer (score 0):

your problem does not seem a big deal. the problem is that you are using 'the editor' of PyCharm. 
see this picture below of my system:
[image]

when you right-click on a .py file and choose 'Edit with PyCharm', you use the simple editor of PyCharm. not the Debugger.
If you click on anywhere else on the window(not on a file), you see the option 'Open Folder as PyCharm Project' (if you do not have this option, reinstall PyCharm and check this option in PyCharm setup wizard), like the picture below:
[image]
now if you choose this option, PyCharm will open your whole folder as a project, and you have python console, terminal, debugger, and whatever you want.
these 2 pictures below, show differences between this 2 mode:

- Edit with Pycharm:
  you can see in this mode you have no option for running and debugging your code. just an editor.
  [image]
- Open Folder as PyCharm Project 
  in this mode, you will see you have full options for running and debugging, python console, terminal, and so on...
  [image]



  so you see, in your first picture, when you select 'Open File in Project' in PyCharm Editor mode, it looks like you are opening this file by pressing 'Open Folder as PyCharm Project' in your folder. so if you open your folder as a PyCharm project, you do not need to do this all the time for running you code.
  [image]

Comment: I am not right clicking and then choosing an option from the menu, I am just double clicking on the .py file. - I ended up re-installing Pycharm as you suggested because I wasn't getting the "Open folder as a Pycharm Project" and that works now, but I used to be able to double click on a .py file and go straight to that view. Have they changed something in Pycharm recently after an update?

Comment: still, you are opening it in editor mode. as you can see in this link from PyCharm site: "Everything you do in PyCharm, you do within the context of a project. It serves as a basis for coding assistance, bulk refactoring, coding style consistency, and so on." so if you want to use PyCharm for running and debugging your code, you must open your folder as a project. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/quick-start-guide.html#why-project